# Serialize a class array members as flattened

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

Is it possible with Json.Net to convert the following fragment to have its array members flattened ?

```
{
  "format": "json",
  "artist": "artist1",
  "description": [
    "description1",
    "description2"
  ]
}
```

Like this :

```
{
  "format": "json",
  "artist": "artist1",
  "description": "description1",
  "description": "description2",
}
```

In short, an object would look like a dictionary but with duplicate keys allowed.

Tried to use a custom JsonConverter such as the following :

```
internal class MyConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var strings = (string[])value;
        foreach (var s in strings)
        {
            writer.WritePropertyName(writer.Path);
            writer.WriteValue(s);
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(string[]);
    }
}
```

But a JsonWriterException is raised when writing property's name :

*Token PropertyName in state Property would result in an invalid JSON object. Path ''.*

Creating such invalid object is fine as I have no plans on deserializing it later, actually I need that for creating an url parameters string in the form of :

*format=json&artist=artist1&description=description1&description=description2*

Is it worth the effort to try to use Json.Net infrastructure for achieving this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution to the problem : JsonTextReader

```
private static string GetUrlParameters(string json)
{
    JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json));
    string path = null;
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        JsonToken tokenType = reader.TokenType;
        switch (tokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.PropertyName:
                path = reader.Path;
                break;
            case JsonToken.Integer:
            case JsonToken.Float:
            case JsonToken.String:
            case JsonToken.Boolean:
                string item = string.Format("{0}={1}", path, reader.Value);
                list.Add(item);
                break;
        }
    }
    return string.Join("&", list);
}
```